# Is it possible to export schema through Salesforce Schema builder?

Tags: salesforce, schema, erd

I'm looking for an option to export ERD diagram from Salesforce Schema builder. Do we have any option/way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's an idea to upvote, only 11 years old... https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdaatUAB/able-to-print-schema-from-schema-builder

You might have some luck with https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/610/how-to-print-export-the-schema-builder. I've tried SchemaSpy and the result is bit ugly but ok set of html pages with images and clickable regions to navigate the "database"

Answer (score 0):

You can use LucidChart to import your objects as ERD items. Then when you drag them onto the diagram, it creates the relationship connectors. https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/salesforce-schema-import